# how do I converting jsonarray to jsonobject in android

Tags: json

I want to send my data to the server and I want to convert jsonarray to jsonobject. How do I go about it.

```
[
   {
      "price":"12000",
      "problems":"toyota",
      "selected":true
   },  
   {
      "price":"10500",
      "problems":"KIA",
      "selected":true
  }
]
```

to

```
{
  "price":["12000", "10500"],
  "problems":["toyota","KIA"],
  "selected":["true","true"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in a function (I named it `convert()`) and you'll get the wanted result:

```
function convert() {

    /** 
     * you can presumably leave out this initialization 
     * as you already have this JSON-Array somewhere else in your code. 
     * I put it in just for presentational purposes.
     */
    const source = [
            {
                'price': '12000',
                'problems': 'toyota',
                'selected': true
            },
            {
                'price': '10500',
                'problems': 'KIA',
                'selected': true
            }
        ];

        const destination = { price: [], problems: [], selected: [] };

        source.forEach(element => {
            destination.price.push(element.price);
            destination.problems.push(element.problems);
            destination.selected.push(element.selected);
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Of course you can restructure all this. The most important part is to define the `destination` object containing the matching arrays and the `forEach()`-loop which maps the JSON-array's content into your new structure.